# Is AWS, specifically the load balancer service affected by SSL "Heart Bleed" exploit?

Tags: security, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I can't find information on what versions they're using. I'd expect AWS to make a statement about this, because it's a pretty big deal, but again, can't find anything.

To answer my own question, YES it is vulnerable. Use this site to test:

http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 7):

Your question sounds very similar to this thread on AWS Forums:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=535235&tstart=0

If you have not checked that before, in short; Yes AWS ELBs are affected by heartbleed and Amazon released this statement mentioning they are working on it:

http://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/heartbleed-bug-concern/

They have not provided a timeline yet.

For Amazon Linux images, patch is available through yum repositories. (Updated package: openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1)

Comment: `openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1` - 1.0.1e is downlevel. 1.0.1g remediates the issue. Are they backpatching so that its impossible to track versions?

Comment: @jww I believe they do not maintain 1.0.1g as a separate branch. 1.0.1e-37.66 backports fix for heartbleed.

Comment: you can check their status here: http://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/aws-services-updated-to-address-openssl-vulnerability/